# Java - Caps Lock status on form focus gained

Tags: java, focus, frame

Well, I have the following code to check the status of caps lock, when I change the status of the caps lock with focu in the form there is no problem but when I minimize the form and change the status of caps lock and back to maximize the form not update the status of the caps lock. Any ideas?

```
/**
 *
 * @author joepa37
 */
public class FocusExample extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    public FocusExample() {
        initComponents();
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")                     
    private void initComponents() {

        capsLockLbl = new javax.swing.JLabel();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        addFocusListener(new java.awt.event.FocusAdapter() {
            public void focusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {
                formFocusGained(evt);
            }
        });
        addKeyListener(new java.awt.event.KeyAdapter() {
            public void keyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {
                formKeyPressed(evt);
            }
        });
        getContentPane().setLayout(new java.awt.GridLayout());

        capsLockLbl.setText("CAPS LOCK : ");
        getContentPane().add(capsLockLbl);

        pack();
    }                    

    private void formKeyPressed(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                
        if (evt.getKeyCode() == java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK) {
            updateStatus();
        }
    }                               

    private void formFocusGained(java.awt.event.FocusEvent evt) {                                 
        updateStatus();
    }                                

    private void updateStatus(){
        boolean isCapsLockOn = java.awt.Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit ().getLockingKeyState ( java.awt.event.KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK );
        capsLockLbl.setText(isCapsLockOn ? "CAPS LOCK ON" : "CAPS LOCK OFF");
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new FocusExample().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    private javax.swing.JLabel capsLockLbl;         
}
```

Comment: Kill the `KeyListener`, probe the [`Toolkit#getLockingKeyState`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Toolkit.html) instead!

Comment: For the record, `Toolkit#getLockingKeyState` won't solve this problem, because it only updates while a Java window is active and has focus.  (Annoying, but done for security reasons.)  Using the Toolkit API is still better than the `KeyListener` approach, but isn't sufficient for this specific problem.

Comment: Similar Question..
If anyone has solution... please help
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61359316/trying-to-read-scroll-lock-status-using-java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution, is not so professional but it works. What I did is add a robot to press to times caps lock when the form comes into focus. Two times to return to the original state that the user left the last time, apparently it updates the event perfectly.

```
this.addWindowListener(new WindowAdapter() {
    @Override
    public void windowActivated(WindowEvent we) {
        try {
            java.awt.Robot r = new java.awt.Robot();

            //first time to update the event
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);

            //second time to return to the last time status
            r.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
            r.keyRelease(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);

        } catch (Exception e) {}

      updateStatus();

    }
}
);
```

Comment: THAT'S TOTALLY DISGUSTING... and solves the problem!  The AWT Toolkit isn't allowed to detect state updates that happen outside of an active AWT window, so forcing an update like this is the only portable solution currently available to us.  Thanks!