# Trying to read Scroll Lock status using JAVA

Tags: java, multithreading, jar, automation, awt

I have the below lines of code using which i am trying to read status of scroll lock.

I get the status of scroll lock when my program starts.
However i am willing to get the status realtime.
Please guide on the below

```java
package assignment;

import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

import org.omg.PortableServer.THREAD_POLICY_ID;

public class ScrollLockOnOff {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException 
    {
        while(true)
        {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            Toolkit toolkit=Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
            System.out.println(toolkit.getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_SCROLL_LOCK));
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Duplicate of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786282/toolkit-getdefaulttoolkit-getlockingkeystate-never-updates-during-program).

Comment: yes this is a possible duplicate.. and i believe there is no solution to the actual question in that post..

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "get the status realtime"? In your above example, it seems that you want to get the status once per second. What is the behaviour that you see?

Comment: as per the code written.. i should get the status of scroll lock every second...
However, i get the status which was at the time when program started....

Comment: What’s the point of importing `org.omg.PortableServer.THREAD_POLICY_ID`?

Comment: Why is this tagged `multithreading`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It’s an interesting behavior, to correctly report the initial state but to depend on subsequent event processing (having a focused top level window or tray icon) for updates.

If we had a way to reset the AWT to its initial state, it should solve the issue. If we don’t find such a possibility, the straight-forward fix is to run a new JVM. Since a new JVM with the same properties will use resources in cache or even shared memory, the overhead is much smaller as it may sound. Performing the action once a second is no problem:

```
public class ScrollLockOnOff {
    public static void main(String[] args)
                       throws InterruptedException, AWTException, IOException {

        if(args.length == 1 && args[0].equals("VK_SCROLL_LOCK")) {
            System.exit(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit()
                .getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_SCROLL_LOCK)? KeyEvent.VK_SCROLL_LOCK: 0);
            return;
        }

        ProcessBuilder b = new ProcessBuilder(
            Paths.get(System.getProperty("java.home"), "bin", "java").toString(),
            "-classpath", System.getProperty("java.class.path"),
            ScrollLockOnOff.class.getName(), "VK_SCROLL_LOCK"
        ).inheritIO();

        while(true) {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            int state = b.start().waitFor();
            if(state != 0 && state != KeyEvent.VK_SCROLL_LOCK) {
                System.err.println("failed");
                break;
            }
            System.out.println(state == KeyEvent.VK_SCROLL_LOCK);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the closest solution i guess we can have...
though starting jvm again seems an overhead....

Comment: Or wait until this behavior gets fixed. Considering that there are bug reports dating back to JDK 1.4 times, we can only speculate whether and when this will happen. The overhead has been mentioned in the answer. On today’s JVMs, it’s less than it was in the past, thanks to shared libraries, class data archive, memory mapping, etc.

Comment: i agree.. will accept this answer if we don't have another answer till tommorow....

Answer (score 0):

If you want to listen for keypresses of scroll-lock implement a [key listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html) looking for `KeyEvent.VK_SCROLL_LOCK`.

Typically (and the reason for the `getLockingKeyState()` method) you'd be listening for other events (e.g. up/down arrow key presses) and then would query the state of the scroll lock key to decide how to interpret that event. But it should be possible to listen for scroll-lock presses just like any other key.

I don't have a scroll-lock key on my laptop's keyboard, but when I run the `KeyEventDemo.java` example from the linked tutorial I see it captures `KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK` events; a "KEY PRESSED" event fires when Caps Lock is turned on, and A "KEY RELEASED" event fires when it's turned off. Scroll Lock should behave similarly.

I added the following line to the end of `KeyEventDemo.java`'s `displayInfo()` method to see the "realtime" Caps Lock state:

```
displayArea.append("Caps Lock: " +
    Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK) +
    newline);
```

If you do the same with `VK_SCROLL_LOCK` you should see the scroll-lock state turn on and off when the key is pressed.

Whenever you call `getLockingKeyState()` you're getting the *current*, "real-time" status of that key, so just call that method whenever you need to know the key's status.

Comment: i am not willing to listen to keypresses..
i just want realtime scroll lock status using getLockingKeyState()..

Comment: You should get the "realtime" status of the scroll lock key whenever you invoke that method. If that's not what you're seeing an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) would help others debug your issue.

Comment: i have provided a minimal code in the question which reproduces the issue..

Comment: I have done the same with scoll lock and yet i get the status which was at the time when the program started...

Comment: Can you try a different machine? Perhaps something is at issue with your hardware. What happens if you call `setLockingKeyState()`? You can also poke around the source code: https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk/jdk11/file/tip/src/java.desktop/share/classes/java/awt/Toolkit.java

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22786282/toolkit-getdefaulttoolkit-getlockingkeystate-never-updates-during-program

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. You'll only see updates to `setLockingKeyState()` if you're running a GUI and have application focus.

Comment: so is there a way to achieve this in java?

Comment: I suspect not, at least not with AWT/Swing. There are some keyloggers written in Java, but probably not part of the JDK.

Comment: See for example these libraries:  https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook and https://github.com/kristian/system-hook as a potential solution if you do not have a Java AWT Frame in focus / running in foreground

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I have faced something similar and I solved by using a [Robot.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Robot.html) When you want to know whether scroll lock is on, and get the correct status of it, let the Robot press/release the button 2 times. However, (probably a bug or so), the status is not correct if you do it instantly. You will have to add a delay (not human-noticable) in order to get the proper status. That means, you will have to do it in a background thread, and not in the EDT, since this will cause EDT to freeze (when the threads sleeps, events cannot take place).

See this example (some comments inside code). It always give the correct status of scroll lock, even if window was not in focus. Also, there is a global key listener, so you know whether the scroll lock is pressed (but only fires when window has focus).

```
public class ScrollLockDetection {
    private static final int SCROLL_LOCK = KeyEvent.VK_SCROLL_LOCK;
    private JFrame frame;

    public ScrollLockDetection() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setSize(400, 400);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.addWindowFocusListener(new WindowAdapter() {

            @Override
            public void windowGainedFocus(WindowEvent e) {
                showScrollLockStatus();
            }
        });
        registerGlobalScrollLockListener();
        frame.setVisible(true);

    }

    private void registerGlobalScrollLockListener() {
        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().addAWTEventListener(event -> {
            if (event instanceof KeyEvent) {
                KeyEvent keyEvent = (KeyEvent) event;
                if (keyEvent.getID() == KeyEvent.KEY_RELEASED && keyEvent.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_SCROLL_LOCK) {
                    showScrollLockStatus();
                }
            }
        }, AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
    }

    private void showScrollLockStatus() {
        ScrollLockDetector scrollLockDetector = new ScrollLockDetector(b -> {
            System.out.println("Scroll lock ON: " + b);
        });
        scrollLockDetector.execute();
    }

    class ScrollLockDetector extends SwingWorker<Boolean, Void> {
        private Consumer<Boolean> consumer;

        public ScrollLockDetector(Consumer<Boolean> consumer) {
            this.consumer = consumer;
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground() throws Exception {
            //First we have to remove all global key listeners so the robot does not fire them
            Toolkit toolkit = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit();
            AWTEventListener[] globalKeyListeners = toolkit.getAWTEventListeners(AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK);
            while (toolkit.getAWTEventListeners(AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK).length > 0)
                toolkit.removeAWTEventListener(toolkit.getAWTEventListeners(AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK)[0]);

            Robot robot = new Robot();
            robot.keyPress(SCROLL_LOCK);
            robot.keyRelease(SCROLL_LOCK);
            Thread.sleep(3);
            robot.keyPress(SCROLL_LOCK);
            robot.keyRelease(SCROLL_LOCK);
            Thread.sleep(3);
            //Re-add the global key listeners
            Stream.of(globalKeyListeners).forEach(listener -> toolkit.addAWTEventListener(listener, AWTEvent.KEY_EVENT_MASK));
            return toolkit.getLockingKeyState(SCROLL_LOCK);
        }

        @Override
        protected void done() {
            try {
                Boolean isScrollLockOn = get();
                consumer.accept(isScrollLockOn);
            } catch (InterruptedException | ExecutionException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(() -> {
            new ScrollLockDetection();
        });
    }
}
```

---

After the declarations in comments (they should exist in question), the best way to achieve whether scroll lock is ON/OFF is to use [a global key listener](https://github.com/kwhat/jnativehook/wiki/Keyboard). When your application starts, it takes the scroll lock status from `getLockingKeyState` and then everytime scroll lock is pressed, you change it.

See this complete example:

```
public class GlobalKeyListenerExample implements NativeKeyListener {
    private static boolean scrollLock;

    @Override
    public void nativeKeyPressed(NativeKeyEvent e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void nativeKeyReleased(NativeKeyEvent e) {
        if (e.getKeyCode() == NativeKeyEvent.VC_SCROLL_LOCK) {
            scrollLock = !scrollLock;
            System.out.println("Scroll lock is:" + (scrollLock ? "ON" : "OFF"));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void nativeKeyTyped(NativeKeyEvent e) {
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            scrollLock = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_SCROLL_LOCK);
            System.out.println("Initial state of scrollock: " + (scrollLock ? "ON" : "OFF"));
            GlobalScreen.registerNativeHook();
            Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(GlobalScreen.class.getPackage().getName());
            logger.setLevel(Level.WARNING);

            // Don't forget to disable the parent handlers.
            logger.setUseParentHandlers(false);
            // Don't forget to disable the parent handlers.
        } catch (NativeHookException ex) {
            System.err.println("There was a problem registering the native hook.");
            System.err.println(ex.getMessage());

            System.exit(1);
        }
        GlobalScreen.addNativeKeyListener(new GlobalKeyListenerExample());
    }
}
```

Now, to check if scroll lock is on, you just check the `scrollLock` variable.

Comment: @Shoaeb Can you explain what "works" means? When window is not in focus and you press scroll lock nothing happens (do you want anything to happen?) BUT when you take the focus back to window, it detects it.

Comment: if the window that is listening to the scoll lock key is not in focus, it will not be able to get the scroll lock status...

lets say my requirement is to read the scroll lock led which is in keyboard...

Comment: @Shoaeb but when you will gain focus, **IT WILL DETECT IT**. Can you let me know what do you want to achieve?  What is the reason to know whether scroll lock is on if user is not in your application?

Comment: i have a application that copies directory from source to destination...
now i want to write a code which in background does the copy if the scroll lock is on and will not copy if it is not on..